# Rock Paper Scissors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

I'm a beginner in Python and I've just finished a Rock, Paper, Scissors simulator in Python. It asks the user to enter paper, rock, or scissors and the program will generate a random number which will convert it to paper, rock or scissors. The program will then print the corresponding result. It also keeps tracks of wins/losses/ties until the user wants to stop playing then prints the prints the results back to the user.

```
import random as r
print("Welcome to my Rock-Paper-Scissor Game")
print("The rules are as follow:")
print("     Paper beats Rock")
print("     Rock beats Scissors")
print("     Scissors beat Paper")
print()
win=0
ties=0
loss=0
i=0
while i==0:
    while True:
        user=input("Do you pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
        if user not in ("Scissors","scissors","paper","Paper","Rock","rock"):
            print("Please enter Rock, Paper or Scissors. ")
            continue
        else:
            break
    computer=r.randint(1,3)
    if computer==1:
        computer="Paper"
    if computer==2:
        computer="Rock"
    if computer==3:
        computer="Scissors"
    if (user=="Paper" or user=="paper"):
        print("You choose paper")
        if computer=="Paper":
            print('\033[0;32m' + "It's a tie! The program also choose paper")
            ties=ties+1
        if computer=="Rock":
            print('\033[1;31m' + "You won! The program choose rock")
            win=win+1
        if computer=="Scissors":
            print('\033[1;36m' + "You lost! The program choose scissors")
            loss=loss+1

    if (user=="Rock" or user=="rock"):
        print("You choose Rock")
        if computer=="Rock":
            print('\033[0;32m' + "It's a tie! The program also choose rock")
            ties = ties + 1
        if computer=="Scissors":
            print('\033[1;31m' + "You won! The program choose scissors")
            win = win + 1
        if computer=="Paper":
            print('\33[1;36m' + "You lost! The program choose paper")
            loss = loss + 1

    if (user=="Scissors" or user=="scissors"):
        print("You choose Scissors")
        if computer=="Scissors":
            print('\033[0;32m' + "It's a tie! The program also choose scissors")
            ties = ties + 1
        if computer=="Paper":
            print('\033[1;31m' + "You won! The program choose paper")
            win = win + 1
        if computer=="Rock":
            print('\033[1;36m' + "You lost! The program choose rock")
            loss = loss + 1
    while True:
        question=input('\033[0;0m' + "Would you like to play again? ")
        if question not in ("Yes","yes","Y","y","no","No","n","N"):
            print('\033[;1m' + "Please only enter yes or no. ")
            continue
        else:
            break
    if question in ("Yes","y","Y","yes"):
        i=0
    if question in ("No","n","no","N"):
        i=1
print()
print("Your final results are as follows")
print("Number of wins:",win)
print("Number of ties:",ties)
print("Number of losses:",loss)
```

Comment: I would use functions like .upper() so that different capitalizations of the same string do not need to be checked.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, so I won't post it as an answer, but I think you could actually use a dictionary  to store who beats who. Checking tie would be (computer == user) and checking if the user won would be (dictionnary[user] == computer) or something like that. It will avoid writing all cases by hand

Answer (score 3):

### Yes/no handling

Don't repeat yourself or reinvent the wheel. There already exists a `distutils.util.strtobool` that does exactly what you're trying to accomplish:

> Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).
>
> True values are y, yes, t, true, on and 1; false values are n, no, f, false, off and 0. Raises ValueError if val is anything else.

You can convert the string to lowercase beforehand. Since `strtobool` raises a `ValueError`, your yes/no handling can be written succinctly like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        question=input('\033[0;0m' + "Would you like to play again? ")
        i = not strtobool(question)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('\033[;1m' + "Please only enter yes or no. ")
```

Notice that `strtobool` returns `1` for truthy values, yet for some reason you have `i == 0` represent "keep going", which is confusing. So I used `not` here, but I recommend either changing that or using proper bools here for readability.

Answer (score 3):

#### Code style

Since you are a Python beginer, you can read the [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements).
This gide will teach you the best practices in Python coding style.
You can use a modern IDE (like PyCharm) do develop in Python. It can found the coding style errors for you.

For instance:

**Missing whitespace aroud operator**, replace:

```
win=0
ties=0
loss=0
i=0
```

by:

```
win = 0
ties = 0
loss = 0
i = 0
```

**Missing whitespace after ','**, replace:

```
if user not in ("Scissors","scissors","paper","Paper","Rock","rock"):
    print("Please enter Rock, Paper or Scissors. ")
    continue
```

by:

```
if user not in ("Scissors", "scissors", "paper", "Paper", "Rock", "rock"):
    print("Please enter Rock, Paper or Scissors. ")
    continue
```

**Remove redundant parentheses**, replace:

```
if (user=="Paper" or user=="paper"):
    print("You choose paper")
```

by:

```
if user=="Paper" or user=="paper":
    print("You choose paper")
```

### Simplify, be Pythonic

**Simplify the comparison to True/False values**, replace:

```
while i==0:
    ...
```

by:

```
while not i:
    ...
```

**Use incrementation**, replace:

```
ties = ties + 1
```

by:

```
ties += 1
```

**Use `str.lower` (or `str.upper`) to simplify your test**, replace:

```
if user not in ("Scissors", "scissors", "paper", "Paper", "Rock", "rock"):
    ...
```

by:

```
user = user.lower()
if user not in ("scissors", "paper", "rock"):
    ...
```

**Choose the right name for your variables/functions/classes**, the `user` variable is not an user but a thing that the user choose.

**Be "positive" as often as your can**, replace:

```
if user not in ("Scissors", "scissors", "paper", "Paper", "Rock", "rock"):
    print("Please enter Rock, Paper or Scissors. ")
    continue
else:
    break
```

by:

```
if user in ("Scissors", "scissors", "paper", "Paper", "Rock", "rock"):
    break
else:
    print("Please enter Rock, Paper or Scissors. ")
    continue
```

**REVIEWED CODE:**

```
while True:
    user_choice = input("Do you pick Rock, Paper, or Scissors? ")
    user_choice = user_choice.lower()
    if user_choice in ("scissors", "paper", "rock"):
        break
    print("Please enter Rock, Paper or Scissors.")
```

Note: the `else` is not necessary.

**Use `if/elif/else` statement (like `switch` in other languages)**, that way, developers understand that all conditions are mutually exclusive.
Again, turn the values to lower case (or uppercase) to match the user choice.

Replace:

```
if computer == 1:
    computer = "Paper"
if computer == 2:
    computer = "Rock"
if computer == 3:
    computer = "Scissors"
```

by:

```
if computer_choice == 1:
    computer_choice = "Paper"
elif computer_choice == 2:
    computer_choice = "Rock"
else:
    computer_choice = "Scissors"
```

Note: you can also use a dictionary to do the mapping between integers and things:

```
mapping = {1: "paper", 2: "rock", 3: "scissors"}
computer_choice = mapping[computer_choice]
```

Read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences) and you'll find a function to choose a value in a collection of values.

**REVIEWED CODE:**

```
computer_choice = r.choice(["paper", "rock", "scissors"])
```

I think, you understand the idea…

Answer (score 2):

This section

```
computer=r.randint(1,3)
if computer==1:
    computer="Paper"
if computer==2:
    computer="Rock"
if computer==3:
    computer="Scissors"
```

can be simplified with `random.choice`:

```
computer=r.choice(["Paper","Rock","Scissors"])
```